# Word order of 'Ich markiere den Text mit Textmarker.'

Tags: word-order

I have watched a video. there were 3 rules in word structure and it stated sentences like 'Ich gebe meiner Freundin eine Blume.' So my question is if dativ precedes akkusativ why does this sentence is 'Ich markiere den Text mit dem Textmarker'.

Comment: Possibly answered by: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/35937/dative-or-accusative-object-comes-first

Comment: @infinitezero: Your link is the same as Raketenolli's. In any case Blavius' answer is more relevant since there is a prepositional phrase involved.

Comment: It would help to include a link to the video where you got this information. We could then see if the video is wrong or if you're misinterpreting it somehow. In general, be very suspicious of German grammar rules that start with "Always ..." or "Never ...".

Comment: @infinitezero: Okay, it was just a bit confusing since the links are labelled differently. I thought I was experiencing déjà vu for a moment there :)

Comment: The rule is *the dative **object** (usually) precedes the accusative object*, which is not the same thing. Mind the preposition.